# How to use JdbcInterceptor to retry queries

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat, database-connection

I want to retry MySql queries in cases of deadlock which will be removed if I can simply retry.

I use apache tomcat jdbc pool library for mysql connection pooling and it has concept of JdbcInterceptor objects which can be attached to existing Connection object. I wonder how to use these interceptors to do a query retry. How can I know if query has thrown an exception and I should retry?

I am thinking of doing something like this but I am confused in getting the right retry logic:

```
public class JdbQueryRetryInterceptor extends JdbcInterceptor {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(JdbQueryRetryInterceptor.class);



    @Override
    public void reset(ConnectionPool parent, PooledConnection con) {


    }
}
```

And I have added this interceptor in the pool properties:

```
p.setJdbcInterceptors("com.test.mysql.JdbQueryRetryInterceptor");
```

I am not sure if it can be done at interceptor level however since tomcat docs say that it can be done so I want to go with this approach.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

> Ability to configure custom interceptors. This allows you to write custom interceptors to enhance the functionality. You can use
>   interceptors to gather query stats, cache session states, reconnect
>   the connection upon failures, retry queries, cache query results, and
>   so on. Your options are endless and the interceptors are dynamic, not
>   tied to a JDK version of a java.sql/javax.sql interface.

Comment: What makes you think a deadlock can be removed by just retrying? Deadlocks indicate a design error in your application. Don't try to code around them: fix them.

Comment: Yep you are right not all deadlocks can be removed but this one can. I saw innodb status and two threads locked the same page. I think this particular query could be retried.